# Boost Log V2 Library Android Linking

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk, boost-log

I am trying to build Boost 1.55 Log v2 library on Android using NDK 9C. 
I have used the patches and build the boost using build-android.sh including thread,iostreams,random and log options. 
I have used the other features of Boost and they have worked. But there seems to be linking problem with the Log V2 which I could not solve with the existing solutions. I keep getting the same "undefined reference" error.
On the web people solved this problem including "#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK" but it did not work for me. Do you have any idea what might be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Console Output:

```
10:35:45 **** Build of configuration Default for project BoostLogLib ****
/home/guven/Desktop/IDP/adt/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-9 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:BoostLogLib: non-system libraries in linker flags: /home/guven/Desktop/IDP/adt/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a -lboost_system-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_iostreams-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_random-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_log-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_log_setup-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_program_options-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_chrono-gcc-mt-1_55    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: BoostLogLib <= BoostLogLib.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libBoostLogLib.so
jni/BoostLogLib.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::get()'
/home/guven/Desktop/IDP/workspace/3rdparty/Boost-for-Android/boost_1_55_0/boost/log/attributes/attribute_name.hpp:80: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const*)'
jni/BoostLogLib.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::set_filter(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::filter const&)'
/home/guven/Desktop/IDP/workspace/3rdparty/Boost-for-Android/boost_1_55_0/boost/log/attributes/value_extraction.hpp:232: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name) const'
/home/guven/Desktop/IDP/workspace/3rdparty/Boost-for-Android/boost_1_55_0/boost/log/attributes/value_extraction.hpp:233: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::end() const'
/home/guven/Desktop/IDP/workspace/3rdparty/Boost-for-Android/boost_1_55_0/boost/log/attributes/value_extraction.hpp:241: error: undefined reference to 'boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libBoostLogLib.so] Error 1

10:35:50 Build Finished (took 4s.138ms)
```

the sample "helloworld" project code as below.
BoostLogLib.h file

```
#ifndef BOOSTLOGLIB_H_
#define BOOSTLOGLIB_H_

#include <jni.h>

#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_boostloglib_BoostLogLib_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* BOOSTLOGLIB_H_ */
```

BoostLogLib.cpp file

```
#define BOOST_LOG_USE_CHAR
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK

#include "BoostLogLib.h"


#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;

//[ example_tutorial_trivial_with_filtering
void init()
{
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int start_logging()
{
    init();

    return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_boostloglib_BoostLogLib_print(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){

    start_logging();
    jstring result = env->NewStringUTF("Hello world!!!"); // C style string to Java String
    return result;
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := BoostLogLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := BoostLogLib.cpp
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++0x

LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -lpthread
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I/home/guven/Desktop/IDP/workspace/3rdparty/Boost-for-Android/boost_1_55_0
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L/home/guven/Desktop/IDP/workspace/3rdparty/Boost-for-Android/build/lib -lboost_system-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_iostreams-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_random-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_log-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_log_setup-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_program_options-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_55 -lboost_chrono-gcc-mt-1_55

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -frtti

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_MODULES := BoostLogLib
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the problem is caused because of the static library linking
The problem is that it looks for symbols like this:

```
boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::set_filter
```

But instead the library has symbols:

```
boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::set_filter
```

if #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK  is removed and  APP_STL is changed in Application.mk from gnustl_static to gnustl_shared. Then the problem goes away. But it should not be in this way.

Note that it only applies if library is build as below

```
./build-android.sh --boost=1.55.0 --with-libraries=date_time,filesystem,program_options,regex,signals,system,thread,iostreams,random,log,serialization,graph $PATH_TO_NDK
```